# Somando coluna com filtro em Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Eu tenho um csv com três colunas:

```
+----------------------------+-----------------+--------------+
| txtDescricaoEspecificacao  |  txtFornecedor  |  vlrLiquido  |
+----------------------------+-----------------+--------------+
```

Eu queria que ele somasse o `vlrLiquido` sempre que o 
`txtDescricaoEspecificacao == "CASCOL COMBUSTIVEIS PARA VEICULOS LTDA"` e juntasse em um DataFrame mostrando o `txtFornecedor` junto com o `vlrLiquido` somado total, alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

O primeiro passo é filtrar os DataFrame onde `vlrLiquido` é `"CASCOL COMBUSTIVEIS PARA VEICULOS LTDA"`: `df[df['txtDescricaoEspecificacao'] == 'CASCOL COMBUSTIVEIS PARA VEICULOS LTDA']`

Depois pegamos esse DataFrame filtrado e agrupamos os dados iguais da coluna `txtFornecedor` com a regra de soma para a coluna `vlrLiquido`: `.groupby(['txtFornecedor']).agg({'vlrLiquido':sum})`.

Tudo junto fica:

```
df[df['txtDescricaoEspecificacao'] == 'a'].groupby(['txtFornecedor']).agg({'vlrLiquido':sum})
```

Answer (score -2):

```
df.query("txtDescricaoEspecificacao == 'CASCOL COMBUSTIVEIS PARA VEICULOS LTDA'")["vlrLiquido"].sum()
```

**EXEMPLO COMPLETO**

1. Criando um dataframe:

```
_ = {"txtDescricaoEspecificacao" : ["CASCOL COMBUSTIVEIS PARA VEICULOS LTDA", "AAA LTDA","BBB LTDA","CASCOL COMBUSTIVEIS PARA VEICULOS LTDA","CASCOL COMBUSTIVEIS PARA VEICULOS LTDA","AAA LTDA"],
"txtFornecedor" : ["FORNECEDOR 1","FORNECEDOR 2", "FORNECEDOR 1", "FORNECEDOR 1","FORNECEDOR 1", "FORNECEDOR 2"],
"vlrLiquido" : [10,10,9,9,8,8]}
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame(_)
```

**APLICANDO O FILTRO E A SOMA**

```
df.query("txtDescricaoEspecificacao == 'CASCOL COMBUSTIVEIS PARA VEICULOS LTDA'")["vlrLiquido"].sum()
```